# Magento 2 GrahQL Product Sorting does not work for the product query with category Filter

Tags: magento2, sorting, query, graphql

I have this graphQL query

```
{ 
  products(filter: {category_id:{eq: "5"}, price: {from: "0", to: "999999"}}, pageSize: 10,  currentPage: 1
 sort: {position: DESC}) {
    total_count
    items { 
      id
      name 
      sku 
      }       
    aggregations{
        count
        label
        attribute_code
        options{
            count
            label
            value
        }
    }
    sort_fields{
        default
        options{
            label
            value
        }
    }
  } 
}
```

> Referring document - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/graphql/queries/products.html

ProductAttributeSortInput we have a position. **I am assuming this position should sort the product based on position set for the product in the category which category ID I am passing to filter the collection.** But It sort by product creation date (Can say Product ID.).

Do I have a correct understanding of this position for APIs? Or it works differently for the GraphQL APIs

I have tried CategoryList GraphQL API as well and there also the same result. Now I have the option to go through the code.

Comment: DId you found any solution?

Comment: @RohanHapani See my answer

Answer (score 0):

To sort by an attribute for a product you'll need to edit your graphql schema.

Edit etc/schema.graphqls and copy the "products" query, or create your own query like this, by adding your own type for sorting, in the `sort` column, in this case `SortBySortAttributeInput`

```
type Query {
    my_custom_products_query (
        search: String @doc(description: "Performs a full-text search using the specified key words."),
        filter: ProductAttributeFilterInput @doc(description: "Identifies which product attributes to search for and return."),
        pageSize: Int = 20 @doc(description: "Specifies the maximum number of results to return at once. This attribute is optional."),
        currentPage: Int = 1 @doc(description: "Specifies which page of results to return. The default value is 1."),
        sort: SortBySortAttributeInput @doc(description: "Specifies which attributes to sort on, and whether to return the results in ascending or descending order.")
    ): Products
    @resolver(class: "Magento\\CatalogGraphQl\\Model\\Resolver\\Products") @doc(description: "The products query searches for products that match the criteria specified in the search and filter attributes.") @cache(cacheIdentity: "Magento\\CatalogGraphQl\\Model\\Resolver\\Product\\Identity")
}
```

Then under that in etc/schema.graphqls add the `SortBySortAttributeInput` type

```
input SortBySortAttributeInput {
    my_sort_column: SortEnum
}
```

Add in this input type all the attributes from a product you might wish to use for sorting your results, and give them SortEnum as input type that's accepted.

Then in your graphql query add the sorting you wish, on the columns in a Product that correspond to the columns you defined in SortBySortAttributeInput.

```
my_custom_products_query (
    sort: {my_sort_column: ASC}
    ) {
    items {
        sort
        sku
        id
        name
        ...
        ...
```

To recap: In your graphql schema's defined `SortBySortAttributeInput` you define all the attributes in a product you might wish to sort on. name, id, sort_order, my_special_attribute, etc...
As type for the input you define SortEnum.

This resolves in your graphql query to:

```
   sort: { product_column_name_defined_in_SortBySortAttributeInput: ASC | DESC }
```

Please note that ASC and DESC need to be written in uppercase. Graphql will return an error message saying that it couldn't find asc in SortEnum, did you mean ASC.